# How to save "pages" as a template

Tags: sharepoint-server, template, pages

I need to make some testing and  I need to copy primary site's "Pages" to the development site. In there, the Pages should be imported named "OriginalSitePages" and will not intefere with development site's Pages.
Is there a workaround, because Pages don't have the option to save as template

Answer (score 0):

You need to create page layout:

**See this:**

- http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-page-layouts-in-sharepoint-2013-using-sharepoint-designer/

Comment: The development server is actually a copy from the primary site. So all layouts, master pages are there.